# Items.Count returning 0 for a list box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use the code below to store the items from the list into a session. For some reason when I debug the code the count is returning 0 even though there are multiple items in the list box? Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    NameTextBox_AutoCompleteExtender.OnClientItemSelected = "getSelected"
End Sub

 Protected Sub cmdNext_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
    Dim n As Integer = NPListbox.Items.Count
    Dim arr As String() = New String(n - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        arr(i) = NPListbox.Items(i).ToString()
    Next
    Session("arr") = arr

    Response.Redirect("~/frmDescription.aspx")
End Sub 


 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function getSelected(source, eventArgs) {
      var s = $get("<%=NameTextBox.ClientID %>").value;

      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.text = s.substring(s.length - 10);
      opt.value = s.substring(s.length - 10);

      document.getElementById('<%= NPListbox.ClientID %>').options.add(opt);

  }
```

Comment: `NPTextbox` is a `ListBox`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I originally had a textbox there so I kept it the same name I will change it

Comment: Where do you fill the ListBox?

Comment: I have a textbox above it with an autocomplete extender and when the item is selected it fills the listbox

Comment: Can you wrap this code into the autocomplete extender rather than trying to access it later?

Comment: I am not sure how I would do that from my asmx code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess that you do not have any logic in your `Page_Load` to populate the listbox, based upon what it had when you finished the autocomplete extender logic. Since, you do not, then when the click event fires after the `Page_Load` your values are gone.

Put the logic that executes on selection of the autocomplete extender in a method and have your `Page_Load` call that, like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Put call here to populate the listbox results from autocomplete extender selection
    PopulateListBox()
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateListBox()
    ' Go to whatever resource you are using to get the values for the list box
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Since you are depending upon using a client-side function to grab the values from the autocomplete extender and populating the listbox that way, you need to mimic that logic in your `Page_Load` on the server-side, because it will be too late if you try to use the client-side one, since you need the data server-side and all of the server-side events happen before the client-side logic in a server post back.

You need to do something like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Only do this when page has posted back to the server, not the first load of the page
    If IsPostBack Then
        ' Put call here to populate the listbox results from autocomplete extender selection
        PopulateListBox()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateListBox()
    ' Get value from text box
    Dim textBoxValue As String = Me.NameTextBox.Text

    ' Create new item to add to list box
    Dim newItem As New ListItem(textBoxValue)

    ' Add item to list box and set selected index
    NPListbox.Items.Add(newItem)
    NPListbox.SelectedIndex = NPListbox.Items.Count - 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What is in `getSelected`?

Comment: Maybe I have to get the items in the javascript section "getSelected"?

Comment: Okay, you cannot call the client-side `getSelected` until after you have completed the server-side code. In other words, it will be too late for you to retrieve the list from your client-side function, because the `cmdNext_Click()` method will execute on the server before the client-side code can. You need to simulate the logic the `getSelected` function is doing in your `Page_Load`. See `UPDATE:` in my answer.